# D language: Are function signatures with constraints considered equal if they refer to the type directly or the parameter names?

Tags: d

Given the below function signatures (and their constraints), would they be considered the same? Both pass my unittests, so I am led to believe they may be, but I'd like to know if they are truly identical or if they are different (but behave the same):

Here, the signature constraint refers the parameter names (I realize the runtime information is not available, my assumption is that the compiler uses these to refer to the types of haystack and needle):

```
T[] find(T, E)(T[] haystack, E needle) 
  if(is(typeof(haystack[0] != needle) == bool)) 
{
  // ...
}
```

Now, if I update to refer to the types T and E, it still works. I like this form better because it's explicit that my signature constraint is looking the types (and not runtime information)... and well it's more concise:

```
T[] find(T, E)(T[] haystack, E needle) 
  if(is(typeof(T != E) == bool)) 
{
  // ...
}
```

Are my assumptions correct or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

personally I'd use `if(is(typeof(T.init != E.init) == bool))` to ensure it's about the vars of the type

(and then when you want T to be a range (and losing the array notation it'd be `if(isInputRange(T) && is(typeof(T.init.front != E.init) == bool))`)

---

edit: best way to test things like this is by expanding the test case:

if we take a different function:

```
int binarySearch(T,E)(T[] haystack, E needle)
    if(is(typeof(haystack[0] < needle) == bool)) {
//...
   return -1;
}
```

this compiles and works as you'd expect (barring implementation details...)

but

```
int binarySearch(T,E)(T[] haystack, E needle)
    if(is(typeof(T < E) == bool)) {
//...
   return -1;
}
```

doesn't (calling `binarySearch([1,2,3],0);` on it doesn't compile)

however like my original answer:

```
int binarySearch(T,E)(T[] haystack, E needle)
   if(is(typeof(T.init > E.init) == bool)) {
    //...
    return -1;
}
```

this does work like expected

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so are you saying that the two examples of what I posted above are the same or just behave the same? (And how does that equate to the example you posted)? Thanks @ratchetfreak

Comment: Thanks for your response and the expanded answer. It helps me see that they are not entirely equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

My first tought is that the function signature is not related to static constraints. When used your function is *generated*, and so is its signature, I think.
Constraints are just to disambiguate and/or generate compile time errors, my assumption is that you can't talk about signature of a template function, but maybe, as signature template :)

In your example, I believe you want to check convertibility from one type to another, say `E` to `T`, (is this `int` in the array of `double`), which is written with `is(E : T)` or using convenient template `isImplicitlyConvertible` in std.traits.

In your first example, you check that comparison of values `haystack[0]` and `needle` is possible, but there is no chance that you can find `3.14` in an array of `int`, however you can compare an int to a float, so this `static if` seems to be too permissive.